# Export for Enterprise deployment requires login, But I have logged in to XCode

Tags: ios, xcode

[image]

When I try to Export IPA for enterprise deploy I see this message but I am logged in to XCode with my team apple ID.

Comment: try to login with the apple ID on which that enterprise account is created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that the Apple Developer account that I used to login is not an enterprise account.